# How do I format email name and address when there is a comma inside string?

Tags: awk, sed

I have strings with email addresses such as this one:

```
"Name1, Last name1" <email1@example.com> , "Name2 " <email2@example.com>, email3@example.com
```

and I want to extract name and email address in rows in order to sort them out and check for duplicate addresses:

```
"Name1, Last name1" <email1@example.com>, 
"Name2 " <email2@example.com>, 
email3@example.com
```

I managed to split them to columns but a comma inside quotes creates new line 
Here is the code I tried:

```
sed "s/,/,\n/g"
```

Comment: Try `sed 's_>,_>,\n_g' filename`

Comment: Clear your glasses, please.

Comment: @EdMorton There are 2 people providing 2 different answers, one with sed and the other with awk. Both of them are adequate, but they helped me, so I gave them an upvote. I don't see the third one.

Answer (score 2):

I am considering that you have missed a `>` after first email example(since you output shows a `>` after 1st email), if this is the case try following then once.

```
awk '{gsub(">, ","&"ORS)} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed it now.
Thanks

Comment: @konenas, give it sometime, when you see few answers, then you could select anyone of them as correct one too, cheers.

Comment: No, Ed, it could be anywhere

Comment: @Ed I've changed a little bit the code provided and now it works. From all the answers your was the best, but you deleted it.